# Problema guardando datos en array

Tags: c++

En los 30 espacios de mi array días sólo se me guarda la información del ultimo valor, por ejemplo: Si `dias[30]` es 80, se me guardan las 30 líneas con 80.

```
void guardar(tDias& dias) {
    ofstream archivo;
    archivo.open("datos.txt", ios::out);

    double texto;

    if (archivo.fail()) {
        cout << "No se pudo abrir el archivo" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        texto = dias[i];
        archivo << texto << endl;
    }

    archivo.close();
}
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la definición de `tDias`?

Comment: const int duraciondelMes = 30;
typedef double tDias[duraciondelMes];

Comment: @pedrocc_13 añade la definición a tu pregunta, no a los comentarios. ¿Cuál es el contenido de `dias`?